# My website don't load after installing Joomla

Tags: joomla, content-management-system, joomla2.5, joomla1.5, joomla3.0

I copied joomla 3.1.5 files into /public_html/joomla and then installed it. After instalation I must type "www.MyDomainName.com/joomla" in order to load my website and if I just type "www.MyDomainName.com", this message is shown :

```
**Forbidden**

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

please help me

Answer (score 1):

First of all check permissions of `/public_html`

Is there is an **index.php** or **index.html** file in `/public_html`? If not and there is Options -Indexes directive the result will be forbidden

Comment: Could you please answer me with more details?

Comment: Do you use shared hosting or you run the site on own web server? If you have own server what operating system does he run?

Comment: If you run apache web server on linux machine, then the user who runs apache process has to have permission to read /public_html. In linux permission can be checked by running following command ls -al in public_html's parent dir and result will be something like 
drwxr-xr-x 24 vkdimitrov vkdimitrov    4096 Oct 10 22:47 public_html

Comment: My website is run on web server which is ran on linux machine.

Comment: do you have shell access, if yes could you please try and paste the result of "ls -al" in public_html's parent dir?

Comment: is there a .htaccess file in /public_html and what is inside?

Comment: yes, there is. how can i see content of it?

Comment: The size of it is 0 byte. And i think it is empty file.

Comment: what about index.php or index.html in public_html is there any?

Comment: there isn't index.php in /public_html but in /public_html/joomla there is a file with this name.

Comment: so you want to see the content of /public_html/joomla when open www.mysite.com instead of www.mysite.com/joomla?

Comment: yes, exactly. I want to see content of /public_html/joomla after I when I open www.MySite.com

Comment: the easiest way is to change DocumentRoot directive in VirtualHost's configuration for mysite.com from /public_html to /public_html/joomla. That is if you use apache web server. The other way is with mod_rewrite

Comment: could you explain your way with more details? thanks

Comment: if its not a problem for you to have joomla files directly into /public_html you can try this http://docs.joomla.org/Moving_the_site_among_directories/sub-directories

Comment: otherwise here is the mod_rewrite case http://www.ianholden.com/how-to/hide-joomla-subdirectory/